# Custom Moya Plugin

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, moya

I have an issue with creating my own Moya Plugin, with the following code:

```
import Foundation
import Moya
import Result

public final class CustomPlugin: PluginType {

    public func willSend(_ request: RequestType, target: TargetType) {
        print("willSend")
    }

    public func didReceive(_ result: Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType) {
        print("didReceive")
    }
}
```

I get the following error from the Xcode compiler:

> Generic type 'Result' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2, but expected 1)

I'm able to fix the compiler error by changing the

```
public func didReceive(_ result: Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType)
```

To

```
public func didReceive(_ result: Swift.Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType)
```

But after this change, the didReceive method isn't called.

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to remove public keywords?

Comment: Swift 5.1 introduced it's own `Result` type, so you're just having name conflict. `Moya` delegate method expects their own `Result` ofc.

Comment: @Ahmet I tried both with and without the public keyboard without luck. And the willSend() is working independent on public keyboard

Comment: @user28434 I tried changing the 
didReceive(_ result: Swift.Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType) 
to 
didReceive(_ result: Moya.Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType) which gives the compiler error: 
No type named 'Result' in module 'Moya'

Comment: @PAK, it's `Result.Result`

Comment: Already tried. ```didReceive(_ result: Result.Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType)``` says  ```Result' is not a member type of 'Result<Any>```. Suggestion from Xcode: ```Result<Any>.Result``` but doesn't work.

Comment: @PAK `import enum Result.Result` instead of `import Result` and use `Result`, and it has just *one* generic type parameter.

Comment: That doesn't confirm to the protocol in PluginType saying: 
`func didReceive(_ result: Result.Result<Moya.Response, Moya.MoyaError>, target: TargetType)`

Answer (score 2):

In Moya, Result is defined as a generic enum.

```
enum Result<T>{
    case success(T)
    case failure(String)
}
```

Where generic parameter type could only be one, but you have applied two parameters to the generics as Result.

Comment: The public protocol says: 
```func didReceive(_ result: Result.Result<Moya.Response, Moya.MoyaError>, target: TargetType)```. How should I implement your answer?

Comment: Can you give me the link to your github repo? this way it would be much easier to fix the problem and save us some time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your Moya version there are different possibilities:

### If you're using Moya 13.*:

We use a bundled framework for the `Result` type (which you imported). This might be then mismatched with Swift's own `Result` type (that is a different type and thus you got a warning).

Replacing `Result<Response, MoyaError>` with `Swift.Result<Response, MoyaError>` just says that you are using a different `Result` type and because of that you are implementing a different method than Moya asks you to (and you don't get a warning because all of the plugin methods from `PluginType` are optional for you to implement).

The real solution should be a way to use the `Result` type provided by the `Result` framework, which would mean something similar to the following:

```swift
public func didReceive(_ result: Result.Result<Response, MoyaError>, target: TargetType) {
    print("didReceive")
}
```

Note: If it's not working, then check if you have a compatible `Result` framework version and if imported it in the plugin file.

### If you're using Moya 14.* (which is currently in the alpha stage):

Most likely do not import `Result` and you should be fine :)

Comment: I just updated to 14.0.0-beta.2, and still getting the compiler error `Generic type 'Result' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2, but expected 1)`.

My function: 

`func didReceive(_ result: Result<Moya.Response, Moya.MoyaError>, target: TargetType) {
        print("Test")
}`

Comment: @PAK what's your Swift version? What's your package manager? What dependencies do you have?

Comment: Argh, I found the problem. I had a local model named Result. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just import Result in plugin file solve my problem.

I think it is because compiler use Swift.Result instead of Third party Result,
so it will execute the default protocol extension.

I'm using Xcode 11.3, Swift 5, Moya 13.0.1, Result 4.1.0